# How to interact with a .aspx using Java?

Tags: java, asp.net, web-scraping

I'd like to write a java program that has the ability to input information onto an asp, and then read back the data that is returned from the asp.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Is there an easier/more elegant solution than web scraping?

Comment: use Ajax to post info on ASP and then return the result back to jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Java code to work in ASP, it has to be compiled byte-code that can be read by the CLR. A quick Google search of "Java" + ".NET" yielded this: http://www.janetdev.org/

Another thing you could do is just learn C#. If you already know Java, there hardly is a learning curve.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to programming, so I didn't even think to google java and .net, I just tried java and .asp XO. Good suggestion on the C#, I actually know some of that, but I need to stick with the Java

Comment: i think you are trying to acces a classic asp not a .net aspx page, right? the anwser is wrong then and .net won't help you here. what you have to do is call the classic asp page with a http GET or POST request, send the needed parameters with that request and parse the http response.

Comment: Actually I didn't even consider that as if it were a difference. But I just double checked and it is an .aspx page.